# Angularjs ng-repeat race condition in setting dropdown value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I had the problem of getting resource data from an API, loading that into a dropdown select, and setting the selected value of the dropdown. Basically it was trying to set the value of the dropdown before it was populated. I have two different ways to do this, but was wondering if anyone had a "better" way, or a "better practice" way. Here are my two ways.

Option 1: Directive attached to ng-repeat element

Controller

```
$scope.users = User.query();
$scope.dude={
    name: "Dude",
    id: 3
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="userSelect" ng-show="users.length">
    <option ng-repeat="user in users" choose dude="dude">{{user.username}}</option>
</select>
```

Directive

```
.directive('choose', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.user) {
                if (scope.user.id === scope.dude.id) {
                    $("#userSelect").val(element.val());
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Option 2: Watch for the users length to change (the call is returned, and the dropdown is populated)

Controller

```
$scope.users = User.query();
$scope.dude={
    name: "Dude",
    id: 3
}
$scope.$watch('users.length', function() {
    $("#userSelect").val($scope.dude.id);
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="userSelect" ng-show="users.length">
    <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.id}}>{{user.username}}</option>
</select>
```

Any opinions on which one is better practice? Or if there is any other better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, promises are your friend for this sort of thing.  I'm going to use $http instead of resources, because I'm more familiar with it, but I'm pretty sure recent version of 
resources return promises (or can).

Also.. no jquery in your controllers.  Use directives like ng-model to change input values.
Also using ng-options to populate the options for a select is more powerful than using ng-repeat on an "option" element.

Here's what a lot of my code looks like (except that I'm using jsonp here instead of just get).  http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/142/

CONTROLLER:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    // The id we want to select when the data loads:
    var desiredId = 3;

    // Overly complicated $http request so that I can load with jsonp:
    // You could normally use just $http.get()
    $scope.users = $http.jsonp('http://www.json-generator.com/j/geku?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function(d) { return d.data.result; });

    // Use the returned promise to set the selection when the data loads:
    // I'm using the "underscore" library function "findWhere" to set my
    // model to the object I want selected:
    $scope.users.then(function(d) {
        $scope.uservalue = _.findWhere(d,{id:desiredId});
    });

}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">  
    {{uservalue | json}}
    <select ng-model="uservalue" ng-show="users.length" ng-options="user.name for user in users">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I like it. Setting the scope variable in the callback makes way more sense. I love it when I over complicate things. Thanks man.